# Using regex to find something in the middle of a href while looping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For "extra credit" in a beginners class in Python that I am taking I wanted to extract data out of a URL using regex.  I know that there are other ways I could probably do this, but my regex desperately needs work so...

Given a URL to start at, find the xth occurrence of a href on the page, and use that link to go down a level.  Rinse and repeat until I have found the required link on the page at the requested depth on the site.

I am using Python 3.7 and Beautiful Soup 4.
At the beginning of the program, after all of the house-keeping is done, I have:

```
starting_url = 'http://blah_blah_blah_by_Joe.html'
extracted_name = re.findall('(?<=by_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^.html]*', starting_url)
selected_names.append(extracted_name)
# Just for testing purposes
print(selected_name)  [['Joe']]
```

Hmm, a bit odd didn't expect a nested list, but I know how to flatten a list, so ok.  Let's go on.

I work my way through a couple of loops, opening each url for the next level down by using:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup('a')
```

Continue processing and, in the loop where the program should have found the href I want:

```
# Testing to check I have found the correct href
print(desired_link)  <a href="http://blah_blah_blah_by_Mary.html">blah 
    blah</a>
type(desired_link) bs4.element.tag
```

Correct link, but a "type" new to me and not something I can use re.findall on. So more research and I have found:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a') :
    tags = link.get('href')
    type(tags) str
    print(tags)
       http://blah_blah_blah_by_George.html 
       http://blah_blah_blah_by_Bill.html 
       http://blah_blah_blah_by_Mary.html
       etc.
```

Right type, but when I look at what printed, I think what I am looking at is maybe just one long string?  And I need a way to just assign the third href in the string to a variable that I can use in re.findall('regex expression', desired_link).

Time to ask for help, I think.

And, while we are at it, any ideas about why I get the nested list the first time I used re.findall with the regex?

Please let me know how to improve this question so it is clearer what I've done and what I'm looking for (I KNOW you guys will, without me even asking).

Comment: If using BS is not a requirement, don't use it in this case. All you're doing is collecting anchors, and regex is good at that. My issue with this question is the fact that it is an extra credit for an assignment, which means that you should be banging your head against the wall trying to solve this issue by yourself (but also by using already existing information sources like SO)

Comment: Since you say "Hmm, a bit odd, didn't expect a nested list" You're appending a list as an additional item to the end of a list (you're not merging two lists). This means that you are adding **one** item to `selected_names`, and that one item is a list, which apparently only contains `Joe`. Check the documentation for `.append()`. (`.findall()` returns a list, not a single item)

Comment: Using BS is a requirement.  The extraction of names from the link is not required (using regex or by any other means).  And thank you Daniel for your explanation about the nested lists.  I can see that now.

Comment: What isn't really clear about the question is that the title states _something in the middle of a href_. I interpret this as `<a href='http://example.com/THIS_HERE/but_not_this/MAYBE_ALSO_THIS'>This can be ignored</a>` Are you interested in the entire URL, or do you also need to further extract information from the URL?

Comment: The challenge I set myself was to capture a part of the URL using regex, AFTER having proven to myself that I could do it using the accepted method for the class.  I should have been satisfied with just proving that I could write a regex to extract what I wanted.  But having made it that far, I wanted to see if I could use it as an alternative way of achieving the same results. I can see in retrospect that one method or the other one, but not combining both, was probably the way to go.  I learned a lot in the effort, and am still learning things from the comments and answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've printed every link on the page. But each time in the loop tags contains only one of them (you can print `len(tags)` to validate it easily).

Also I suggest replacing `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` with `\w+` - it will catch letters, numbers and underscores and is much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for that. I thought the problem was serious and complex because of all of the dire predictions I had received (another site)  about trying to use regex in cases like this.  Just needed to move the findall to a different place in the program and the whole thing worked fine the first time.  Teaches me not to be put off by all of the discouraging prophecies. The experiment only saved me three lines of code, but now I know that I can do it, if I want to.  And thank you for the  \w tip.  I'll use that in the future as well.